# Wamp versão do php 5.3 ou menor

Tags: php, wamp

Galera, seguinte, encontrei um sistema em PHP que não utiliza interface PDO para conectar no banco, é mysql_connect() ainda. Hoje eu uso a versão do Wamp 2.4.9 e a do PHP 5.5.12. Eu gostaria de obter uma versão mais antiga do PHP para não precisar trocar todas as conexões com o banco para PDO. Fazendo algumas pesquisas existem alguma extensões para usar uma versão mais antiga do PHP, mas nenhumas delas eu consegui instalar ou executar no Wamp, alguém tem uma versão anterior do Wamp ou alguma maneira de rodar um PHP com uma versão mais antiga? Acredito que pelo menos precisa ser PHP 5.3.

Baixei deste link já: https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/Wampee%202.1/

Mas acontece este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Procure as versões anteriores aqui: https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/

Comment: Então, eu já fiz isso, mais quando baixo esta´versão: https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/Wampee%202.1/ dá uma erro na hora de instalar, veja na pergunta editada a imagem
Sabe o que é isso?

Answer (score -1):

este erro acontece quando seleciona uma pasta que não é a raiz da instalação do wamp. 
veja se sua pasta de instalação tem o nome: "wamp" ou "wamp64", etc.

obs: se está tentando instalar outra versão do wamp, deverá instalar em outra pasta, não a c://wamp/ que já existe. Agora se quiser instalar um addon, utilize este link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/Addons/Php/ e escolha a versão desejada, lembrando que para instalar deve-se selecionar a pasta raiz do seu wamp.